# Merge Rows Alternately From 2 Excel Sheets

Tags: excel

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCafY.png)                                         [Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yufm4.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJRxA.png)

Hi there,

I want the achieve something like the above example. There are more than 4000 rows for each sheet.

Can anyone help me in this case? Anyone's help will be really appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add them ;-)
create a new sheet and then use the formula

```
=[A.xlsx]Tabelle1!A1 + [b.xlsx]Tabelle1!A1
```

You can achieve this by clicking open all 3 Tables

```
Goto A1 on the result table
type = and click on A1 on Table A 
type + and click on A1 on Table B 
Remove the $ signs
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [article](https://www.excelcampus.com/install-power-query/) to find out how to use **Power Query** on your version of Excel. It is available in **Excel 2010 Professional Plus and later versions**. My demonstration is using **Excel 2016**.

Steps are:

1. Add both your `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` to the Power Query Editor;
2. Add an **Index Column** starts from `0` in the query of `Sheet1` and add another **Index Column** starts from `1` in the query of `Sheet2`;
3. **Append** `Sheet1` with `Sheet2`;
4. **Sort** the new table by the `Index` column, **filter** out `null` in any column, and **remove** the `Index` column, then you should have the combined table as desired.

**Close & Load** the output to a new worksheet (by default).

[image: Demo]